# Continue Streaming on Orientation change

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I have a music streaming service in my activity. My problem is when orientation changes downloading process starts from beginning. I know activity recreated on orientation change. I want my activity to ignore changing orientation. I tried some methods like adding `android:configChanges="orientation"` or add onConfigurationChange(newConfig) to my activity but none of them works.
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this....

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have to add in your AndroidManifest.xml file for orientation and for screenSizes

```
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" >
```